# How do I detect if headphones are connected (via the jack) in bash?

Tags: terminal, applescript, audio, bash, headphones

I have a script, and I want it to behave differently if headphones are connected. How can I get this information?

I tried using [SwitchAudioSource](https://github.com/deweller/switchaudio-osx), but its output is the same, whether or not the headphones are connected:

```
~/tmp
❯ SwitchAudioSource -c
Built-in Output

~/tmp
❯ SwitchAudioSource -a
Built-in Microphone (input)
Background Music (input)
Background Music (UI Sounds) (input)
Built-in Output (output)
Background Music (output)
Background Music (UI Sounds) (output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483083/how-to-get-notifications-when-the-headphones-are-plugged-in-out-mac/):

```
if system_profiler SPAudioDataType | grep --quiet Headphones; then
  echo plugged in
else
  echo not plugged in
fi
```